# Table rows inserted by Jquery not functioning like table rows from original HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a page that contains a table with the following format:

```
    <table id="gigsTable">
        <tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Location</th><th>Remove</th></tr>
        <tr class="gigRow">
            <td><input name="date" type="text" value="Date goes here"></td>
            <td><input name="time" type="text" value="Time goes here"></td>
            <td><input name="location" type="text" value="Location goes here"></td>
            <td class="remove"><input name="remove" type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
```

When the checkbox in the remove column is clicked its parent row fades out and then is removed using the following jQuery:

```
    $("#gigsTable tr .remove input").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).remove();
            rowCount--;
        });
    });
```

I also have a button that adds a row to the table when clicked:

```
    $('#addGig').click(function() {
        $('#gigsTable tr:last').after('<ROW FORMAT FROM HTML>');
        rowCount++;
    });
```

This all works fine however when I try to remove a row that is inserted using the above method nothing happens. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you set yur remove function when page loads and that doesn't contains new elements. So try to do with `live`    function of Jquery which will bind click event to your new elements too.

```
 $("#gigsTable tr .remove input").live("click",function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).remove();
            rowCount--;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Live is slow and has been deprecated. Please don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The `click` event handler can only access elements which are present when the page is initially loaded. To control dynamically added elements use `on` or `delegate`.

Also, rather than `parent().parent()`, you could use `closest('tr')`

Try this:

```
$("#gigsTable tr .remove").delegate('input', 'click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        rowCount--;
    });
});
```

Or if you are using jQuery 1.7+, use `on`.

```
$("#gigsTable tr .remove").on('click', 'input', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        rowCount--;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of direct event `click()`.

It will autosubscribe all newly created controls when you are inserting rows.

Answer (score 0):

The rows you add have not been bound to the `click` event, you'll need something like `on` or `live` depending on your version of jQuery.